# Calculation the Correlation Matrix of a Random Observation Vector

Tags: probability, matrices, correlation

I've googled and looked around on StackExchange but I can't quite find the answer. I'm trying to calculate the correlation matrix R. Below I've included a screenshot of some text that explains how. This is exactly my scenario. My actual textbook uses the same equation as found in 3.26, but I don't understand how to go from 3.26 to 3.27. It's clear to me that multiplying the column vector times the row vector will produce an L-by-L matrix, but I don't understand how I can take the expected value of this. To me it seems that taking the expected value would give me a L-by-1 matrix of the form:

$$
        {1 \over L}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        (x_1(t)\times x_1^*(t))+(x_1(t)\times x_2^*(t))+...+(x_1(t)\times                   x_L^*(t)) \\
        (x_2(t)\times x_1^*(t))+(x_2(t)\times x_2^*(t))+...+(x_2(t)\times x_L^*(t)) \\
        \vdots \\
        (x_L(t)\times x_1^*(t))+(x_L(t)\times x_2^*(t))+...+(x_L(t)\times x_L^*(t)) \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I know this is wrong, but I don't really see any other way to do it. I don't have a really strong grasp of statistics but I would think this is how you take the expected value of a random variable. Thank you for your help!

[image: Correlation Matrix Calculation]

Comment: Perhaps the expectation isn't the average of $L$ elements, but the average, for each of the $L \times L$ elements, over time from $0$ to $T$ as $T \to \infty$?

Comment: I.e., the first element would be $\lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{t = 0}^T x_1(t) \times x^*_1(t) \, dt$.

Comment: As I understand it though $ x_1(t), x_2(t), ..., x_L(t) $ are all unique discrete points, i.e. a single complex number. I don't see how I could take the average of these two numbers over time, as the individual point $ x_L(t) $ is a recorded point and won't change over time. I could be mistaken in my understanding though, I'm kind of at a loss.